# C# open IE9 window and attach

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com

I have a website that uses pre-installed IE plugins to provide secure communication. I don't have access to this plugins code, so if I want to parse pages from this server I have to do it with IE. Otherwise error message shows up.

I want to create a C# program that will open this site and get it's body. 
I've tried to open the IE using
InternetExplorer ie = new InternetExplorer();
unfortunately this page caused not loading of plugins or not reacting to javascript that should make redirection.

I'm trying to do it with solution provided in http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=9683 However there's a problem - I cannot attach to the IE after creating the process.

```
          ShellWindows m_IEFoundBrowsers = new ShellWindowsClass();
          foreach(InternetExplorer Browser in m_IEFoundBrowsers) {
              if(Browser.HWND == (int)m_Proc.MainWindowHandle) {
                  _IE = Browser;
                  break;
              }
          }
```

this code causes InvalidCastException. When I took a look at the Process tree, I've realised that my app launches console, that launches IE - that's the problem as far as I understand. Please help me in attaching to newly opened IE window... I've tried getting the parent of process running Browser, however it failed...

Comment: I don't know what is `attach` (is it like debugging it?), but you can try normal ways to find process, [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/bae77616-b107-48a0-b830-938a73594c5e/closing-ie-in-c?forum=ieextensiondevelopment).

Comment: By attach I mean obtain InternetExplorer object that will allow me manipulate ie. Solution that is in example is nice, I've thought about it, however decided to resign, as the name of IE window mustn't be always the same. Or can I for example start IE and give him a special title (or any other value) to later comparison? For example start IE with title set to some random number and then search for this number in title?

Comment: Your first problem is that IE has changed a bit in the past 9 years (the solution you're looking at is dated 2005).  In particular, I suspect that tabbed windows and low-privilege changes have broken that particular method.

Comment: I see. So that's outdated as hell and noone has done it since 2005... I must stay with autoit then...

Answer (score 0):

Locate the browser by finding which browser.Document is HTMLDocument and the LocationName or LocationURL specified.  Attach that browser instance to your InternetExplorer object by typecasting browser as InternetExplorer.  This code works with IE 11 on my system, and allows interaction with that IE browser instance.

```
InternetExplorer ie = null
// Launch IE program

// Get all browser objects
ShellWindows allBrowsers = new ShellWindows();
if (allBrowsers.Count == 0)
    throw new Exception("Cannot find IE");

// Attach to IE program process
foreach (InternetExplorer browser in allBrowsers)
{
    if (browser.Document is HTMLDocument && browser.LocationName == "My Test Web Site")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found IE browser '" + browser.LocationName + "'");
        ie = (InternetExplorer)browser;
    }
}

if (ie == null)
     throw new Exception("Failed to attach to IE");
```